# "Boost " library issue-" undefined reference error" while compiling using cmake and make

Tags: multithreading, c++11, boost, cmake, autobahnws

I am working on WAMP and crossbar. I am trying to compile and build the executable using `cmake` and `make` commands. The `cmake` is doing fine i.e no errors during `cmake` but during `make` command I am facing the errors shown below. I come across linking Boost library while compiling but am not getting how to do with that with `cmake`.

Below is the log for make:

```
      /usr/bin/cmake -H/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77 -B/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build/CMakeFiles /home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build'
make -f CMakeFiles/Example77-wamp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Example77-wamp.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build'
cd /home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77 /home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77 /home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build /home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build /home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build/CMakeFiles/Example77-wamp.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build'
make -f CMakeFiles/Example77-wamp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Example77-wamp.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'CMakeFiles/Example77-wamp.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build'
[ 33%] Built target Example77-wamp
make -f CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build'
cd /home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77 /home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77 /home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build /home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build /home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build/CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target Example77Client
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build'
make -f CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build'
[ 44%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -I/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src-gen -I/usr/local/lib/cmake/CommonAPI-3.1.12/../../../include/CommonAPI-3.1 -I/usr/local/lib/cmake/CommonAPI-WAMP-0.7.0/../../../include/CommonAPI-0.7  -Wall -O0 -std=c++0x -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP -pthread -g   -o CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o -c /home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp
[ 55%] Linking CXX executable Example77Client
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -Wall -O0 -std=c++0x -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP -pthread -g  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o  -o Example77Client -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--as-needed /usr/local/lib/libCommonAPI.so.3.1.12 
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `get_parameters(int, char**)':
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:107: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:107: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:107: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:108: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::add_options()'
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:109: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, char const*)'
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:110: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::bool_switch()'
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:111: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char const*)'
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:113: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char const*)'
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:115: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char const*)'
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:117: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char const*)'
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:118: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char const*)'
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:121: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::variables_map::variables_map()'
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:123: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::basic_parsed_options<char> const&, boost::program_options::variables_map&, bool)'
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:127: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::operator<<(std::ostream&, boost::program_options::options_description const&)'
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:131: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::notify(boost::program_options::variables_map&)'
/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/server/parameters.cpp:134: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::operator<<(std::ostream&, boost::program_options::options_description const&)'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:206: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:208: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:210: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::future_async_continuation_shared_state<boost::future<void>, void, main::{lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}>::launch_continuation()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:4391: undefined reference to `boost::thread::detach()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::future_async_continuation_shared_state<boost::future<void>, void, main::{lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}::operator()(boost::future<void>) const::{lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}>::launch_continuation()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:4391: undefined reference to `boost::thread::detach()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::future_async_continuation_shared_state<boost::future<unsigned long>, void, main::{lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}::operator()(boost::future<void>) const::{lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}::operator()(boost::future<void>) const::{lambda(boost::future<unsigned long>)#1}>::launch_continuation()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:4391: undefined reference to `boost::thread::detach()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::future_async_continuation_shared_state<boost::future<autobahn::wamp_registration>, void, main::{lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}::operator()(boost::future<void>) const::{lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}::operator()(boost::future<void>) const::{lambda(boost::future<unsigned long>)#1}::operator()({lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}) const::{lambda(boost::future<autobahn::wamp_registration>)#1}>::launch_continuation()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:4391: undefined reference to `boost::thread::detach()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::shared_state_base>), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::future_async_continuation_shared_state<boost::future<void>, void, main::{lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}> > > > > >::~thread_data()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:90: undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::shared_state_base>), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::future_async_continuation_shared_state<boost::future<void>, void, main::{lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}::operator()(boost::future<void>) const::{lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}> > > > > >::~thread_data()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:90: undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::shared_state_base>), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::future_async_continuation_shared_state<boost::future<unsigned long>, void, main::{lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}::operator()(boost::future<void>) const::{lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}::operator()(boost::future<void>) const::{lambda(boost::future<unsigned long>)#1}> > > > > >::~thread_data()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:90: undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::shared_state_base>), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::future_async_continuation_shared_state<boost::future<autobahn::wamp_registration>, void, main::{lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}::operator()(boost::future<void>) const::{lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}::operator()(boost::future<void>) const::{lambda(boost::future<unsigned long>)#1}::operator()({lambda(boost::future<void>)#1}) const::{lambda(boost::future<autobahn::wamp_registration>)#1}> > > > > >::~thread_data()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:90: undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x2b8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x2d0): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x2e8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x300): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:439: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(int, std::error_condition const&) const':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:656: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:659: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(std::error_code const&, int) const':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:686: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:689: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:701: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
/usr/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:230: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::~error_with_option_name()':
/usr/include/boost/program_options/errors.hpp:124: undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::error_with_option_name'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::validation_error::validation_error(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)':
/usr/include/boost/program_options/errors.hpp:378: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validation_error::get_template[abi:cxx11](boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t)'
/usr/include/boost/program_options/errors.hpp:378: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::error_with_option_name(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::value_semantic_codecvt_helper()':
/usr/include/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:91: undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::~value_semantic_codecvt_helper()':
/usr/include/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:91: undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::variables_map::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const':
/usr/include/boost/program_options/variables_map.hpp:155: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int, char const*)':
/usr/include/boost/thread/exceptions.hpp:51: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::condition_error::condition_error(int, char const*)':
/usr/include/boost/thread/exceptions.hpp:84: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::thread_data_base::thread_data_base()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:152: undefined reference to `vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::interruption_checker::interruption_checker(pthread_mutex_t*, pthread_cond_t*)':
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:196: undefined reference to `boost::detail::get_current_thread_data()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&)':
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:90: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::interruption_point()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::system::make_error_code(boost::future_errc)':
/usr/include/boost/thread/futures/future_error_code.hpp:49: undefined reference to `boost::future_category()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::thread::start_thread()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:186: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o: In function `boost::thread::~thread()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:261: undefined reference to `boost::thread::detach()'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE]+0x28): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE]+0x28): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvNS_10shared_ptrINS0_17shared_state_baseEEEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueINS4_INS0_38future_async_continuation_shared_stateINS_6futureIN8autobahn17wamp_authenticateEEEvZNSD_12wamp_session17process_challengeEONSD_12wamp_messageEEUlSF_E_EEEEEEEEEEEE[_ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvNS_10shared_ptrINS0_17shared_state_baseEEEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueINS4_INS0_38future_async_continuation_shared_stateINS_6futureIN8autobahn17wamp_authenticateEEEvZNSD_12wamp_session17process_challengeEONSD_12wamp_messageEEUlSF_E_EEEEEEEEEEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvNS_10shared_ptrINS0_17shared_state_baseEEEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueINS4_INS0_38future_async_continuation_shared_stateINS_6futureIvEEvZN8autobahn18wamp_tcp_transport7connectEvEUlSD_E_EEEEEEEEEEEE[_ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvNS_10shared_ptrINS0_17shared_state_baseEEEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueINS4_INS0_38future_async_continuation_shared_stateINS_6futureIvEEvZN8autobahn18wamp_tcp_transport7connectEvEUlSD_E_EEEEEEEEEEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/build.make:98: recipe for target 'Example77Client' failed
make[2]: *** [Example77Client] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:107: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/client_build'
Makefile:86: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I installed the Boost library using "`sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`"

Any suggestion will help me a lot.

Comment: Try posting the errors separately from the entire build log

Comment: @Sisir,   undefined reference to boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
CMakeFiles/Example77Client.dir/src/example77/server/Example77Client.cpp.o:    like this there are too many errors its mainly undefined reference to boost library packages. am not getting how to proceed.

Comment: what is the compiler version and boost version you have installed? also from logs it seems to be linking errors, try to add -lboost_program_options in Cmake or if you can, please post cmake lists also.

Comment: @GauravDhiman  hi sir,  below is the details that you asked for.  And you asked to -lboost_program_options in Cmake  but am not getting how to do it. "Cmake" added in list.
cmake version 3.10.2
libboost-dev Version: 1.65.1.0ubuntu1
compiler
ii  clang 1:6.0-41~exp5~ubuntu1                           
ii  clang 6.0-1:6.0-1ubuntu2                                 
ii  g++ 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3                             
ii  g++ 7 4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                         
ii  gcc    4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3                              
ii  gcc 7 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1

Comment: Please edit the version information into your question.  You can edit your own question, and that's where the version information belongs.  Then delete your response, and flag this comment 'no longer needed', and probably Gaurav's comment too.

Comment: I observe that 65-character paths in front of the file names in the error messages make it hard to find the error message for the file name.  Consider editing the output to avoid repeating `/home/siddhu/Documents/example77_server/example77/src/example77/` (65 characters) so often.  Think in terms of including it in full once and replacing it on subseqent lines with `…/` instead.